# Showing div if condition is true

Tags: php

I asked this question before and got an answer but I want to do something differently. I am creating a social site that let's people message each other. I want to show the div with a blue background if the `opened` column is `== 0`. But what I have now only shows the div in the else column which is blank.

So immediately the background color goes straight to the else color even though the condition is true and it should be showing the blue color. Any help ?

```
public function getConvos () {

    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    $return_string = "";
    $convos = array();

    $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT user_to, user_from, opened FROM messages WHERE
     user_to = ? OR user_from = ? ORDER BY id DESC');
    $query->bind_param("ss", $userLoggedIn, $userLoggedIn);
    $query->execute();
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

    while ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $user_to_push = ($row['user_to'] != $userLoggedIn) ? $row['user_to'] : $row['user_from'];

        if(!in_array($user_to_push, $convos)) {
            array_push($convos, $user_to_push);
        }

        $color = ($row['opened'] == '0')  ? "#DDEDFF" : "";
    }


    foreach ($convos as $username) {

        $user_found_obj = new User($this->con, $username);
        $latest_message_details = $this->getLatestMessage($userLoggedIn, $username);
        
        $return_string .= "<a href='messages.php?u=$username'><div class='user_found_messages'
                        style='background-color: $color;' >
                        <img src='" . $user_found_obj->getProfilePic() . 
                        "' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
                        ". $username ."<br/>".
                        $latest_message_details . "</div></a>";
    }

    return $return_string;
}
```

---

```
.user_found_messages {

padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
height: auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.user_found_messages:hover {

background-color: #e6ffff;
color: #669999;
}

.user_found_messages img {

height: 105px;
float: left;
margin-top: 1px; 
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Your `$color` is overwritten in every iteration.

Comment: @u_mulder so where should I put it ?

Comment: @BrandonT Please share your html code

Comment: @Jay That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happened due to $color overwrite in each iteration.

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $user_to_push = ($row['user_to'] != $userLoggedIn) ? $row['user_to'] : $row['user_from'];

    if(!in_array($user_to_push, $convos)) {
        array_push($convos, $user_to_push);
    }

    $color[$i] = ($row['opened'] == '0')  ? "#DDEDFF" : "";
    $i++;
}

foreach ($convos as $key => $username) {

    $user_found_obj = new User($this->con, $username);
    $latest_message_details = $this->getLatestMessage($userLoggedIn, $username);
    
    $return_string .= "<a href='messages.php?u=$username'><div class='user_found_messages'
                    style='background-color: ". $color[$key]; ."' >
                    <img src='" . $user_found_obj->getProfilePic() . 
                    "' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
                    ". $username ."<br/>".
                    $latest_message_details . "</div></a>";
}
```